How do I modify the Bresenham or midpoint circle algorithm to only draw an arc?
I implemented the Bresenham circle drawing algorithm which draws a full circle. But now I want to change it to only draw an arc.
I have the start point and the end point of the arc.
On the Wikipedia page of the Midpoint Circle Algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm it says under "Drawing incomplete octants"
Then the Bresenham algorithm is run over the complete octant or circle and sets the pixels only if they fall into the wanted interval.
for drawing an arc between two points. However I do not understand what the "wanted interval" is or how to calculate it.
What is the "wanted interval"? How do I calculate it?
I tried setting the pixels between x1 and x2 and y1 and y2 of the start and stop points. However this does not work in most cases.

"I have the start point and the end point of the arc.": can you give an example of all the input parameters?

You need to know one extra point on the required arc or its total length for this problem to have a unique solution. There are many solutions otherwise ranging from a straight line between the two points (shortest) to a circle that just touches each point (or rather one of the two half circles if you just  wanted a single arc).

@MartinBrown I'd use the CCW rule to get away without knowing either the length nor specifying an extra point.

Normally, with Bresenham's circle-drawing algorithm, calculations are performed only for the 0° to 45° section, and the remaining parts of the circle are generated by applying symmetrical transformations. In practice, parameters are computed for the [0°..45°] part, followed by eight symmetrical drawing steps:

Calculation: 0° to 45°.
Plot 1: 0° to 45°.
Plot 2: 90° to 45°.
Plot 3: 90° to 135°.
Plot 4: 180° to 135°.
Plot 5: 180° to 225°.
Plot 6: 270° to 225°.
Plot 7: 270° to 315°.
Plot 8: 360° to 315°.

To draw an arc, you first need to determine its start and end angles, denoted as A and B, assuming A < B (swap if necessary).
For example, to draw an arc from 60° to 120°, only Plot 2 and Plot 3 need to be considered, but since it could be costly to check, let's go for a generic method.
The algorithm uses a coordinate system where the circle's center is at (0,0). Coordinates (x, y) are calculated for the first octant [0°..45°] as usual. Although the current angle should be computed using the arctangent function, this contradicts Bresenham's principle of integer-based calculations. Instead, an approximation of the current angle Θ (as an integer, we use an integer division here) is used:
Θ = (45 . y) / x
In the [0°..45°] range, the arctangent function is almost linear, allowing an integer approximation of the current angle, Acurr, for the current octant. This enables the determination of whether a pixel should be drawn based on symmetry and the following rules:

Plot 1: Acurr = Θ
Plot 2: Acurr = 90 - Θ
Plot 3: Acurr = 90 + Θ
Plot 4: Acurr = 180 - Θ
Plot 5: Acurr = 180 + Θ
Plot 6: Acurr = 270 - Θ
Plot 7: Acurr = 270 + Θ
Plot 8: Acurr = 360 - Θ

For each segment, check whether the current angle falls within the interval [A, B] using:
if ((A<=Acurr) && (Acurr<=B)) then draw_the_pixel;
Otherwise, the pixel is simply skipped. This logic also applies to the first drawing step. Calculation is always performed for the [0°..45°] segment unless you want to optimize further by avoiding unnecessary calculations. However, such optimizations are usually counterproductive, as the overhead of determining special cases often outweighs the cost of unused calculations. Time savings are most significant during pixel rendering.
